# Evaluating $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin x}{1+ \cos^2 (nx)} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Greetings I want to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin x}{1+ \cos^2 (nx)} dx$.

Here is my try: We have that $x\in[0,\pi]$ so $$\cos(n\pi)\le \cos(nx) \le 1.$$ Here I am not sure, but if it's correct then it gives: $$\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(nx)}\le \frac{1}{1+\cos^2(n\pi)},$$ giving $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \sin x dx \le \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin x}{1+ \cos^2 (nx)} dx \le \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin x}{1+ \cos^2 (n\pi)} dx.$$ Since $$\int_0^{\pi} \sin x dx =2$$ By squeeze theorem we may conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\sin x}{1+ \cos^2 (nx)} dx=1$. Could you help me evaluate this, if it's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. The function $\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ isn't monotonic on $[-1,\,1]$.

Comment: Furthermore, the limit seems to be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Atmos I get approximately that answer from numerical experiments.

Comment: @J.G. How big is $n$ that you have tried?  I observe that I fluctuates from [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3m2okoqy7n).

Comment: @GNUSupporter $n=10^{307}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach can be as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2nx}\,dx&\stackrel{(1)}{=}
\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(y/n)}{1+\cos^2y}\,dy=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(y/n)}{1+\cos^2y}\,dy\stackrel{(2)}{=}\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin\big(\frac{t+k\pi}{n}\big)}{1+\cos^2t}\,dt=
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2t}\Big[\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\Big(\frac{t+k\pi}{n}\Big)\Big]\,dt\stackrel{(3)}{\to}\\
&\stackrel{(3)}{\to}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2t}\,dt\cdot\int_0^{\pi}\sin t\,dt=\sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
Explanations:

(1) change $y=nx$,

(2) change $t=y-k\pi$ and use that $\cos^2t$ is $\pi$-periodic,

(3) Riemann summa limit and dominated convergence theorem.

---

For the last integration: rewrite
$$
\cos^2x+1=\cos^2x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x=\cos^2x(2+\tan^2x),
$$
that gives
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\,dx&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\,dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2+\tan^2x}\,d\tan x=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2+t^2}\,dt=\\
&=[t=s\sqrt{2}]=\sqrt{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+s^2}\,ds=\sqrt{2}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: It might be worth including or linking to a proof that $\int_0^\pi\frac{dt}{1+\cos^2 t}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: just multiply top and bottom by $\sec^2 t$ to get$\int_0^{\pi} \frac {d(\tan t)} {tan^2 t+2}$

Comment: @J.G. I have added few lines.